# Is the usage "drinks round mine tonight" correct?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I have seen people saying/texting/emailing "drinks round mine". I am not sure whether that is grammatically correct or is the term "round" short for "around"? If that's the case, is "drinks around mine" or "drinks 'round mine" the right way to write it?

I have seen this usage in UK and it's usually an invite for a drink at their house.

Comment: 'Mine' means my place so yes, it is saying, 'drinks are around at my place tonight'.

Comment: I suggest "drinks round mine" doesn't at all equate with "drinks are around at my place…" Doubtless if it does, you will be able to explain how…

Until then "drinks round mine" is a clear idiomatic phrase while "drinks are around at my place…" is simply unconscionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Round mine" is an extremely informal, casual and conversational British English expression meaning "at (or to) my home", mainly used in texts, emails, and spoken English.